# How to import a class in another C++ header file?

Tags: c++

I meet a problem when constructing a class. class "Graph" import a class "Bag" in another file and use "Bag" as its component.

```
//Graph.h
#ifndef GRAPH_H
#define GRAPH_H
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Bag.h"
class Bag;
class Graph
{
public:
    Graph(int V);
    Graph(std::ifstream& in_file);
    int getV() { return V; }
    int getE() { return E; }
    void addEdge(int v, int w);
    void showadj() ;
private:
    int V;
    int E;
    std::vector<Bag> adj;
};
#endif
```

And "Bag.h" is as follow:

```
//Bag.h
#ifndef BAG_H
#define BAG_H
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
class Bag
{
public: 
    Bag();
    void addBag(int i) { content.push_back(i); }
    void showBag();
private:
    std::vector<int> content;
};

#endif
```

Graph.cpp:

```
//Graph.cpp
#include "Graph.h"
#include "Bag.h"
Graph::Graph(int V) : V(V), E(0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < V; i++)
    {
        Bag bag;
        adj.push_back(bag);
    }
}
```

Bag.cpp(sorry, forget it):

```
#include "Bag.h"
void Bag::showBag()
{
    for (int i : content)
    {
        std::cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

When I try to complie these two classes, an error comes out saying:

```
C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMj4Ybn.o:newtest.cpp:(.text+0x1a2): undef
ined reference to `Bag::Bag()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You need to build `Bag.cpp` into `Bag.o` and link it with `Graph.o`

Comment: Bag.cpp is curiously missing from the question.

Comment: would it work if you just remove `class Bag;` from `Graph.h` and remove `#include "Bag.h"` from `Graph.cpp` (because `Graph.h` already includes `Bag.h`)?

Comment: are you building that from command line ? What command are you using ?

Comment: see answer *Declared but did not define a variable or function*

Answer (score 4):

You need to also implement your constructor `Bag::Bag()` as it is missing in your `Bag.cpp` file.

This is what the error tells you. If you don't need the constructor, then you should remove it from your class definition, which would also solve this error.

An alternative would be to provide an empty constructor in your `Bag.h` file

```
class Bag
{
public: 
    Bag() {}
...
}
```